# Woocommerce cannot alter content of order-table column

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I seem to be able to edit the values that show in the account orders table by just editing the php in the myaccount/orders.php file and adding it to the correct place in my theme.

However no matter what I try to do to the order-total column it will not change.

Every other column I can mess about with the content and it shows but nothing i do makes any difference to the order-total column. Why??

```
echo wp_kses_post( sprintf( _n( '%1$s for %2$s item', '%1$s for %2$s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ), $ordertotal, $item_count ) );
```

This is the standard code for the column but even if I comment it out and add echo "Hello" it still shows the original text. I assume there's an override going on somewhere for this particular column - but where?

Answer (score 0):

Don't even try to mess with WordPress - you'll be at it for hours.

Had to solve this by adding hook for a new column whilst also unsetting the order-total column. Then adding exactly the same code into the custom column and, of course, works perfectly.

Yet more inefficient code added to the site.